# Push button counter from 0-999, but increment in 1, 4 and 6

Tags: counter

I would like to create a push-button counter from 0-999 using 'BCD Decade Counter' and a 'BCD to 7 segment Decoder/Driver' the total of button presses will be displayed on 3 x 7 segment displays (similar to http://www.iamtechnical.com/digital-counter-schematic-diagram).

I am OK with this.

I would also like to implement 2 additional buttons to:

- increment by 4, and,
- increment by 6.

I suspect I may need to connect 2 x 555 to do this for each option.
I think it may be something like this:
https://www.circuitlab.com/editor/#?id=48mxga

I would be really grateful if someone could give me a hint or point me in the right direction.

Many thanks.

Comment: Any particular reason you wouldn't just use a microcontroller?

Comment: no real reason but I am trying to extend my electronics knowledge. Just using circuit as a challenge. Many thanks, Simon

Answer (score 1):

A *pulse doubler* will get you two pulses out per one pulse in.

[image]

*The pulse frequency doubler consists of two gates of the NAND CD4011, and one of the gates forms the phase inverter. By inputting the falling edge inverting phase of the pulse, the circuit will output a pulse with the help of the rising edge and the falling edge of the pulse, so that the aim of double frequency is fulfilled. Source: [SeekIC.com](http://www.seekic.com/circuit_diagram/Automotive_Circuit/The_pulse_frequency_doubler_composed_of_gate_circuits_CD4011.html).*

Since this is running on a CMOS chip you need a pull-up on the input so that it isn't floating.

I'll leave you to figure out how to quadruple a pulse. There are a few catches!

Comment: Many thanks for this, much appreciated. Will try and get my head around how to do the x4 and x6 pulses. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi Transistor, I have been messing around trying to get 4 pulses with no luck. His is possible to give me a hint. Many thanks for your help, Simon

Comment: Did you get the pulse doubler to work? How have you been "messing around"? Breadboard or simulation? Add your designs into your question and we can have a look. The CircuitLab schematic editor (button on the toolbar) has a built-in simulator. No CircuitLab account required.